# Problema com trocar posições em vetor

Tags: c, array

Bom dia!

Usando Dev C++, estou fazendo o seguinte problema em C:

> Faça um programa em C que leia um vetor de 20 posições do tipo real. Troque a 1a posição com a 11a, a 2a com a 12a, a 3a com a 13a, ..., 10a com a 20a.Escreva
>   o vetor modificado.

Este é meu código que não está funcionando:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.c>

main () {
    float vet[20], aux;
    int i;

    clrscr();

//entrada dos dados
printf("Favor informar 20 valores: ");
for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    gotoxy(i*3+2,8);
    scanf("%f", &vet[i]);
}
gotoxy(5,20);

//troca dos vetores
for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    aux=vet[i];
    vet[i]=vet[19-i];
    vet[19-i]=aux;
}

//saida dos dados
gotoxy(2,12);
printf("Vetor modificado: ");
for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    gotoxy(i*3+2,14);
    printf("%i", vet[i]);
}

getch();
}
```

Não consigo identificar o erro. O que pode ser?

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo efetuar a troca dos vetores, na hora de compilar a troca dos vetores ficam:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

O erro está no loop onde você troca os valores. Você está trocando o 1° valor com o 20°, o 2° com o 19° e assim por diante.
O código abaixo faz o que é pedido.

```
//troca dos valores
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    aux=vet[i];
    vet[i]=vet[10+i];
    vet[10+i]=aux;
}
```